# Recommendations for a Full-stack Framework for REST?

Tags: rest, authentication, frameworks, restful-architecture, paas

I am looking for a robust REST framework to eliminate all that boilerplate code with starting up a new REST-only web service (mobile clients). Is there a framework that already has this built-in where I could, for example, simply *build the domain models* and run with it? I would like to see:

- Authentication & User Model
- Logging
- Basic CRUD
- Permissions (for model access)
- Scalability

It seems every web service at a minimum needs the above capabilities. Somebody, somewhere must have written a good re-usable framework with the above capabilities. Any ideas? I would prefer Node.js, Java or even hosting with a PaaS service provider that offers these features.

Answer (score 2):

Spring 3 MVC provides a very nice and simple annotation based framework for REST.
See http://blog.springsource.org/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/ it can be deployed on any java web server like Jetty or Tomcat.

A framework like XAP provides a combined solution of Spring and Jetty plus it's built for dynamic scaling.
See http://www.gigaspaces.com/xap.

Last if you want to easily on board this solution on any cloud CloudifySource provides an open source project which includes XAP capabilities and PaaS.
See http://www.cloudifysource.org

Answer (score 0):

I use **Symfony 1.4** for this. It is an PHP framework. It generates most of what you need for free. The database stuff is also quite easy as the Symfony uses ORM libraries (you can choose but I can recommend Doctrine: http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

For example the whole backend site(admin) generating is a matter of running one command. They have a great e-book fro free. More info here:http://www.symfony-project.org/.

There is also **Symfony 2.X** (http://symfony.com/), which have a lot of new features (e.g. new Doctrine 2.0). Especially with the bundle (plugin) https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle is the RESTful service quite easy.